# IntelliJ Gradle Kotlin Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I have newly installed IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2 (community edition) and I wanted to create a native-kotlin test-app like I did on another PC where everythin worked.
I always get the gradle-error: `Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'] was not found in any of the following sources`

Kotlin plugin 1.5.10 is installed and I have no clue how to get my test-app compiled and the gradle-error removed. Unfortunately, I also did not found a solution in the internet during half a day searching.

Comment: See https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2924#issuecomment-487696904

Comment: Unfortunately nothing of that helped or I'm too stupid to understand what's necessary there

Comment: To choose a correct Gradle JVM (like azul-15) helped and fixed the problem. This can be done e.g. in IntelliJ IDEA in Settings->Build, ...-> Build Tools -> Gradle